# CMake find_package: where did it find the package?

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

In my CMake package, there is a call to `find_package`. This succeeds, great! However, it turns out to be the wrong version of the package. I now want to go and delete that package. However, I have no idea where the heck it is on my system, nor where the `-config.cmake` file is that CMake must have found somewhere. Is there a way to get `find_package` to give me this information? Or at least verbosely tell me where it is searching?

I though this might be in the variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, however that is empty for me. So I guess it is in the default paths somewhere. But CMake searches a lot of places for packages, and I didn't find it in the usual locations that I remember.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah ok, I found a solution here:

https://riptutorial.com/cmake/example/21128/debug-find-package---errors

Turns out there is a special debug flag to make `find_package` tell you where it is searching:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=ON ..
```

Answer (score 13):

As of CMake 3.17, the `cmake` [command line](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) has native support for printing the search directories for **all** of the CMake `find_*` commands. Use the `--debug-find` flag:

```
cmake --debug-find ..
```