# CMake is searching for packages in a strange location

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I have been trying to track down why CMake `find_package` is finding the wrong package in my build. From [CMake find_package: where did it find the package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53410309/cmake-find-package-where-did-it-find-the-package) I learned how to get it to tell me what paths it was searching, and thus where it found the package. But now I need to figure out *why* CMake is searching a certain path, because it is searching in a non-default location for some reason. I checked the variables

```
CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH
CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH
```

but they are empty. The variable

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH
```

is non-empty, but all it contains is

```
/usr/local;/usr;/;/usr;/tmp/pip-req-build-ckl98h8g/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
```

so that is not the reason.

What else can make CMake search some strange prefix?

The exact problem is the following: `find_package(yaml-cpp)` is searching as follows:

```
  ...
  Checking prefix [/]
  Checking file [/yaml-cppConfig.cmake]
  Checking file [/yaml-cpp-config.cmake]
  Checking prefix [/usr/games/]
  Checking file [/usr/games/yaml-cppConfig.cmake]
  Checking file [/usr/games/yaml-cpp-config.cmake]
  Checking prefix [/usr/local/games/]
  Checking file [/usr/local/games/yaml-cppConfig.cmake]
  Checking file [/usr/local/games/yaml-cpp-config.cmake]
  Checking prefix [/snap/]
  Checking file [/snap/yaml-cppConfig.cmake]
  Checking file [/snap/yaml-cpp-config.cmake]
  Checking prefix [/home/farmer/repos/gambit/copy3/build/contrib/yaml-cpp-0.6.2/]
  Checking file [/home/farmer/repos/gambit/copy3/build/contrib/yaml-cpp-0.6.2/yaml-cppConfig.cmake]
  Checking file [/home/farmer/repos/gambit/copy3/build/contrib/yaml-cpp-0.6.2/yaml-cpp-config.cmake]
```

It finds the package config file in that last path. But that is some private build directory of some other code, so I have no idea why `find_package` would search there. Some variable somewhere must have told it to do so, but I don't know which one. I do not want this path to be searched.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think the answer is that CMake follows a horribly complicated procedure to search all over the place for packages. In my case it seems that it found something under

```
~/.cmake/packages/<package>
```

which then must have directed it to the strange prefix I was seeing. Deleting this package registry entry fixed the problem. The full search procedure that CMake follows is described towards the end of the `find_package` documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html